# Issues with replicating results from R to python by writing customised function

Tags: python, r, statistics

I am trying to convert the `R` code to python by writing customised function or without function in python based on this following lines of code

```
customers_df$segment = "NA"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$recency > 365*3)] = "inactive"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$recency <= 365*3 & customers_df$recency > 365*2)] = "cold"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$recency <= 365*2 & customers_df$recency > 365*1)] = "warm"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$recency <= 365)] = "active"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "warm" & customers_df$first_purchase <= 365*2)] = "new warm"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "warm" & customers_df$amount < 100)] = "warm low value"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "warm" & customers_df$amount >= 100)] = "warm high value"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "active" & customers_df$first_purchase <= 365)] = "new active"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "active" & customers_df$amount < 100)] = "active low value"
customers_df$segment[which(customers_df$segment == "active" & customers_df$amount >= 100)] = "active high value"
  table(customers_2015$segment)

active high value  active low value              cold          inactive 
              573              3313              1903              9158 
       new active          new warm   warm high value    warm low value 
             1512               938               119               901
```

Python Function

I tried to replicate the same code as above in python by writing function. However, I was not able to get the same categories as `R` as a well number in each category also differs.

```
def mang_segment (s):
    if (s['recency'] > 365*3):
        return ("inactive")
    elif (s['recency'] <= 365*3) & (s['recency'] > 365*2):
        return ("cold")
    elif (s['recency'] <= 365*2) & (s['recency'] > 365*1):
        return ("warm")
    elif (s['recency'] <= 365):
        return ("active")
      
    
    def mang_segment_up (s):
    #     if (s['recency'] > 365*3):
    #         return ("inactive")
    #     elif (s['recency'] <= 365*3 & s['recency'] > 365*2):
    #         return ("cold")
    #     elif (s['recency'] <= 365*2 & s['recency'] > 365*1):
    #         return ("warm")
        if (s['segment']  == "warm") & (s['first_purchase'] <= 365*2):
            return ("new warm")
        elif (s['segment']  == "warm") & (s['amount'] < 100):
            return ("warm low value")
        elif (s['segment']  == "warm") & (s['amount'] >= 100):
            return ("warm high value")
        elif (s['segment']  == "active") & (s['first_purchase'] <= 365):
            return ("new active")
        elif (s['segment']  == "active") & (s['amount'] < 100):
            return ("active low value")
        elif (s['segment']  == "active") & (s['amount'] >= 100):
            return ("active high value")

active low value     19664
warm low value        4083
active high value     3374
new active            1581
new warm               980
warm high value        561
```

Any pointer/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about the purpose of the function (and if it is working as you expect). If you are seeking to mimic your R code within a function, your syntax can line up much closer with your initial code than it currently is. Assuming you are using panads/numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#toy example
s = pd.DataFrame({'rec' : [2000, 1500, 3000, 750]})

def mang_segment (s):
    s.loc[(s['rec'] > 365*3), 'seg'] = "inactive" # creating a new column seg with our values
    s.loc[(s['rec'] <= 365*3) & (s['rec'] > 365*2), 'seg'] = "cold"
    #etc...

#run function
mang_segment(s) 

#get value counts
s['seg'].value_counts()
```

Here we add a column to our dataframe to capture our values, which we can later summarize. This is different than the `return` function that, if it were working and call appropriately, would not assign it directly to your data frame.

There are other function and ways to get it at this, too. Check out [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as another option.